# Выбрать из таблицы MySQL по одинаковым значениям полей. Как лучше?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица учеников:

```
id | name | addr           | langs   | times | ages
 1 | Иван | Киев;Москва    | рус;укр | пн;пт |    4
 2 | Петр | Харьков;Москва | рус     | пт    |    4
 3 | Олег | Рига           | рус;лит | пн;вт |    5
```

.......

и т.д.

Из этих данных нужно собрать группу- т.е. выбрать из базы учеников с:

1. Одним городом(пример: Москва - подходят Иван и Петр)
2. Одним языком(пример: рус - все подходят)
3. Одним днем недели(аналогично)
4. Одним возрастом.

Один момент: Если идет "подбор" по Москве, например, то подойдут те, у которых указан город Москва+ могут "иметь" и другие города. Также и по другим полям
Как тут лучше поступить? А то пока в голову приходят только идиотские решения

Comment: Вам сейчас там в ответах все пишут, что надо пересмотреть структуру базы, да надо, почитайте про "нормальные формы" http://i-novice.net/6-normalnyx-form-bd/    В данной таблице 2 проблемы с городами, т.к. множество повторений одного названия, то опечатка в одном из них приведет к невозможности поиска. Про переименования городов я вообще молчу. И вы ни как не отличите г. Москва РФ от небольшого селения Москва в США. Ну плюс к этому быстро одним запросом собрать количество учеников по городам крайне сложно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужна команда `FIND_IN_SET()`. 
Если использовать Ваши критерии, то

1. Одним городом(пример: Москва - подходят Иван и Петр) надо искать так: `FIND_IN_SET('Москва', addr)>0`
2. Одним языком(пример: рус - все подходят): `FIND_IN_SET('рус', langs)>0`

Проблема лишь в том, что `FIND_IN_SET()` использует запятую, как разделитель. Т.е. Вам придется еще `REPLACE()` добавить.

Получается, что все москвичи + рус + пт будет так:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Москва', REPLACE(addr, ';', ','))>0 AND
FIND_IN_SET('рус', REPLACE(langs, ';', ','))>0 AND 
FIND_IN_SET('пт', REPLACE(times, ';', ','))>0
```

Однако, @AlexceiShimakov прав: описанный Вами вид структуры базы не самый лучший. Запросы, особенно, если база большая, будут большие, сложные и длинные.
Если у Вас есть возможность менять структуру - очень подумайте над этим.

Ну а про **необходимость** индексов на всех поисковых полях я вообще молчу. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Хранить города, где проживает студент через разделитель, плохая идея, лучше создать дочернюю таблицу "Города" и связать каждый город со студентом. Про остальные поля то же самое(там где данные с разделителем).
2. После вынесения всех данных с разделителем в дочернюю таблицу, вы можете использовать обычный `select` c `where`, где вы можете отфильтровывать данные по городам, по возрастам.
3. Если у вас нет возможности вынести данные в отдельную дочернюю таблицу, то для текущей таблицы я бы использовал функции https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606900/mysql-create-a-simple-function, Функции можно использовать в операторе `where`, также как обычные условия, внутри функций парсил бы поле с разделителем, получал бы массив значений, искал среди массива переданный аргумент(например, какой-то конкретный город), и возвращал бы результат, найдено ли значение в поле.

Answer (score 0):

1.Если лень парсить и у вас ограниченный список городов/языков или что-то еще, воспользуйтесь [функцией сравнения строк](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html) **like**, например:

```
select *
where concat(';',addr,';') like '%;Москва;%
```

2.На будущее - да, не храните так значения лучше, а выносите в отдельную таблицу, или парсите заранее.

3.Для понимания зачем и почему - советую ознакомиться с [нормальными формами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) реляционных бд.

Comment: тогда уж concat(';',addr,';') like '%;Москва;%' что бы случайно не найти по частичному совпадению

Comment: Совет like лучше не использовать, так как на городах типа Уфа и Уфа-Шигири он будет работать не верно. Плюс, при добавлении какого то нового города, вам придется проверять список городов на отсутствие возможной коллизии

Comment: @Mike согласен, поправил ответ, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov да, это временные костыли. Лучше сразу приводить свою бд к нормальной форме.